# How I can prevent Photoshop from adding metadata to a PNG file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png

When I use "Save for Web" in Photoshop it adds a bunch of metadata. For example I saved a 4x4 pixel file as PNG. It should have been around 136 bytes put photoshop added 814 extra bytes, all metadata I don't need or want.

[image]

How can I prevent Photoshop from adding this metadata?

Note: I know I can use pngcrush or other utilties to remove the metadata after the fact. That's not what I'm asking. I'm asking how to get photoshop to stop adding the data in the first place.

Comment: What version of Photoshop? Newer CC versions [idk from exactly which version] now have an alternative option, File>Export>Export as... which even at maximum saves only copyright & contact info, otherwise nothing. It's also considerably faster than the legacy 'Save for Web'

Comment: Sorry. yes. I'm still on CS6 but now that I know CC has that option maybe it's time to finally bite the bullet and give in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Save for Web window, there is a drop down option to select what type of Metadata is stored.

[image: mete data]